# Can I send sms to multiple number using Twilio by passing the recipient number array?

Tags: android, ios, twilio, twilio-php

I am building an application for ios, android, and for web. The application is using REST api to send sms via Twilio api gateway. Now there is a requirement to send bulk sms to customers. Is there any way to **pass** the recipient **mobile number array** to twilio using their api, because I don't want to send to individual customer the same message using foreach loop in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there is no bulk SMS message endpoint. For each message you send you need to make a new request to the API.

I'd recommend doing this using a background process so that it doesn't tie up server processes as that can take quite a long time if you are trying to send a lot of messages.

**Edit**

This answer was correct at the time, however recently the [Passthrough API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html) was announced in which you can send messages to up to 10,000 numbers at the same time. Check out the details in this blog post here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html

Comment: There actually is now! Check out the passthrough API here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html